# The restful api function is good to iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

i'm a mobile-develop engineer.work on IOS platform,using Xcode.

a few days ago.the man server developer has been changed in our company.he said the popular way of developed is using the template whose name was Restful API,then I was starting know something about the Restful api.
what i knew the thought of the template was the server need only developed the just the one http-interface.they didn't care whatever clients how to requested and how hardly used.

i didn't agree that, example in the page.the requirements is search friends depends on the text which user input on search-bar.
the 1.0 version is just searched the information which key included name.maybe we will send the requestPostDate=xx(which user inputed),filter=name. 
the 2.0 version is searched the information which key included name、sex、age or your personal description.but I can't changed the requirements as soon as possible. because i have been wroten filter=name.

what should we did if it should changed in 1.0 versions on AppStore platform. 
so what we did is modified the code which filter=name,sex,age. and upload the new library(IPA),then send it to AppStore.hope it's successful during these days.
what i need to say is if we not using restful api.we can be controlled by server.we just tell them we had a key which is xx,the clients didn't care about what the logic of how to search, it easier? and it changed quickly?the client didn't modified any code.maybe we have Web-platform、IOS-platform、android-platform.

i don't know what's the template your company using now.if it's restful api.please tell me how to fix about the questions what i said before?

Comment: Sorry for the long post Take this potato  Here you have mentioned something about restful api but you haven't mentioned the problem. One problem of filter solved and what is the Question that you said before.

Comment: Send the sql query sentence to your server, get the data from server...Is it the way that an immutable api achieves?

Comment: @季亨达 the server didn't care what your requirements is.they put the data to the api,the clients controlled how to using,and how to filter.
maybe i show example to you that you will understands.the requirements is check hotel-detail-infomation.acturll i just send the data like hotelId to the server.and the server will return the response informations about this hotels which i need display at this page. right?
in fact,the server return the entire informations about this hotels.the data is too large.the client should filter the response which the page need or not need.it's complex.

Comment: @NarendraPandey the problem what i said is the restful api is suitable in IOS platform? maybe is suitable in Web platform,but not suitable in Mobile-developed-platform. do you agree what i said? if not.give me some point which you think is right please.

Comment: Let me just rephrase that, the problem is `What is the suitable restful API for iOS?`. Your sentence construction is confusing.

Comment: @0yeoj  yeah.sorry for that. forgive my english was poor.
in my options.how did you all agree that the restful api is useful to using in IOS platform?

Comment: @Mateen, I would recommend google translate though... Im using my custom made restfulAPI created with PHP... The usefulness of restful API depends from what you want to do and data structure/flow entirely, but in totality (at least for me), using restful api is the best option for communication, validations, remote updates, etc... even for offline apps that needs data/file to downloaded from server.

Comment: @0yeoj tell me how to fix issue i said before yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

the problem what i said is the restful api is suitable in IOS platform? maybe is suitable in Web platform,but not suitable in Mobile-developed-platform.
do you agree what i said? if not.give me some point which you think is right please.